# IPhone iOs 5, need help getting my tab bar at the top to work

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

I wanted to have the tab bar at the top.

So i created a new project in XCode. Added a view and then inside that view i added (scrollbar, text and another view). See picture.

[image: Storyboard view of the MainWindow. Top part is for the tab host, middle is for content and bottom is for copyright]

What i wanted was to have my tab bar at the top. Then in the middle would be the contents from the tab bar and below it a small copyright text. See picture.

[image: All controls that i have added in the StoryBoard]

No idea how to make this correctly. I have tried to create the UITabBarController on the fly and then assign it into the view at the top. (Top white space on the picture dedicated for the tab bar).

Here is my code to init the MainWindow.

MainWindow.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Intro;

@interface MainWindow : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *mainContentFrame;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mainTabBarView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *mainTabBar;

@property (nonatomic, strong) Intro *intro; // Trying to get this tab to show in the tab bar

@end
```

MainWindow.m

```
#import "MainWindow.h"
#import "Intro.h"

@interface MainWindow ()

@end

@implementation MainWindow
@synthesize mainContentFrame = _mainContentFrame;
@synthesize mainTabBarView = _mainTabBarView;
@synthesize mainTabBar = _mainTabBar;

@synthesize intro = _intro;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _intro = [[Intro alloc] init];
    NSArray *allViews = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:_intro, nil];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    _mainTabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [_mainTabBar setViewControllers:allViews];

    [_mainTabBarView.window addSubview:_mainTabBar.tabBarController.view];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setMainTabBar:nil];
    [self setMainContentFrame:nil];
    [self setMainContentFrame:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

What am i missing to get this to work? Wanted the content to end up in the scrollview so that all tabs are scrollable.

Comment: have you tried using tableview?

Comment: Sorry not that into iPhone programming yet. What should i do with a tableview? I get the layout that i want. I just can't get the tabbar to show, tabs in the tabbar and set the content frame to change when a tab is clicked.

Comment: are you talking about this : http://www.google.com.ph/imgres?hl=fil&sa=X&biw=1366&bih=667&tbm=isch&prmd=imvns&tbnid=gz_6JOssG3qITM:&imgrefurl=http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Simple_iOS_4_iPhone_Table_View_Application&docid=-cBPQZ5CRBdt1M&imgurl=http://www.techotopia.com/images/4/4c/Ios_4_iphone_tableview_example.jpg&w=368&h=716&ei=P1T4T_D5GqKKmQWl6sSYBQ&zoom=1

Comment: You want the tabbar at the top?  UITabBarController is designed to show tabs at the bottom (see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006931).  Even if you get it to work, I wouldn't expect any support for it in any iOS updates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS User Interface Guidelines say that the UITabBar has to be at the bottom of the ViewController. You should either create your own GUI for this kind of View or use the "old-fashioned" way. I would not try to hack around the UITabBar as your app may be rejacted by Apple.